# Issue with recognizing multiple columns in GitHub data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, github, multiple-columns

I am trying to read a data set obtained from GitHub and I am encountering column issues. There is unnecessary information in the data set, so I cut it out. When I create a new DataFrame with the information I need, the system does not identify all of the columns. Instead, it views everything as just one column. Would anyone know how to fix this so that I can make the DataFrame output columns, 'r', 'G(r)', 'd_r', 'd_Gr'? Below is my code and outputs.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://github.com/jagar2/Summer_2020_MAT-395-495_Scientific-Data-Analysis-and-Computing/blob/master/homeworks/HW1/ALDalumina.gr?raw=true'
df = pd.read_table(url, skiprows=0)

# from here, the desired data is within rows [123:]
print(df.loc[123:] # this shows desired data

# make new DataFrame
df_new = df[123:]


# output

        History written:      Thu Apr 12 20:03:37 2018
123                         #L r    G(r)    d_r    d_Gr
124     1.000000e-002    8.021935e-002   -7.539822e-...
125     2.000000e-002    1.585036e-001   -1.507964e-...
126     3.000000e-002    2.329669e-001   -2.261947e-...
127     4.000000e-002    3.018208e-001   -3.015929e-...
...                                                 ...
2119    1.996000e+001   -4.029393e-002   -1.504949e+...
2120    1.997000e+001   -4.024680e-002   -1.505703e+...
2121    1.998000e+001   -3.973462e-002   -1.506456e+...
2122    1.999000e+001   -3.877427e-002   -1.507210e+...
2123    2.000000e+001   -3.739258e-002   -1.507964e+...

[2001 rows x 1 columns]
```

How would I get python to recognize these columns? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is being interpreted as containing one slightly longish columns `'History written:      Thu Apr 12 20:03:37 2018'`.

Basically, you need to split up the single column into multiple columns. You can use the below code to get the result as described by you. After you have created `df_new`, you can try:

```
df_final = df_new[1:].assign(r = df_new['History written:      Thu Apr 12 20:03:37 2018'].str.split('\s{3,}').map(lambda x: x[0]), 
              G_r = df_new['History written:      Thu Apr 12 20:03:37 2018'].str.split('\s{3,}').map(lambda x: x[1]), 
              d_r = df_new['History written:      Thu Apr 12 20:03:37 2018'].str.split('\s{3,}').map(lambda x: x[2]), 
              d_Gr = df_new['History written:      Thu Apr 12 20:03:37 2018'].str.split('\s{3,}').map(lambda x: x[3])
             )[['r','G_r','d_r','d_Gr']]
```

This will give you a new dataframe `df_final` with the required 4 columns. You can rename the columns as you deem fit using `df_final.rename(columns = your_column_name_dict)`

```
df_final = df_final.rename(columns = {'G_r':'G(r)'})
```